# В какой момент времени освобождается память класса, который является свойством в структуре?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, best-practice, memory-management

Есть класс (ссылочный тип), который является свойством структуры (тип значение), в момент, когда я инициализирую структуру, я передаю класс в инициализатор, какой ссылкой связывается поле с ссылкой на класс, слабой или сильной? Если сильной, то в какой момент времени свойство отпустит объект, и если это была единственная ссылка, освободит память

```
struct SomeStruct {
  var classRef: MyClass
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для хранения констант можно придумать множество способов. Самые распространенные и простые(может даже самые правильные):

1 Аналог `#define` - глобальные get-переменные. Пример:

```
var someDisabledColor: UIcolor {
    return UIColor.blackColor()
}
```

2 Структуры. Наиболее удобные, отлично структурировать. Пример:

```
struct Config {
    struct Colors {
        static let someBackgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        static let someDisabledColor =   UIColor.blackColor()
    }
    struct Values {
        static let someValue = 10
    }
}

someView.backgroundColor = Config.Colors.someBackgroundColor
```

P.S. `Singleton` обычно для других целей используется. Ну а по памяти если и искать проблемные участки, то точно не здесь.